# Using ng-show along with ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I have two divs (A and B) with opposing ng-shows so that if B is true, B will show up and A will disappear.  However, I want the ability to go back to A, so I've created a FAB button and want it to go back to A on click.  How would I do this?

A looks like this:  `<div ng-show="tasks.length<=0">`

B looks like this: `<div ng-show="tasks.length>0">`

When B is active, I have a md-button that appears with it and I want a user to be able to return back to A when clicked:

```
    <md-button class="md-fab md-primary md-fab-top-left back-fab" aria-label="goBack" ng-click="myFunc()">
      <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
    </md-button>
```

What does myFunc need to look like for me to accomplish this?  Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried? We're here to help you debug and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your myFunc() you must change the tasks = []; to let the b doesnt show and a show again example:

```
myFunc = function() {
    $scope.tasks = [];

    //.... other logic
}
```

i recommend to better use some flag variable for show to handle in more friendly way. something like

```
<div ng-show ="showDiv">  //a
<div ng-show ="!showDiv"> //b
```

and in the logic of your app activate or deactivate.
and in the fab button do the same

```
myFunc = function() { $scope.showDiv = true; }
```